# Picking up my diamond once again

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

In [October 2019](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1200/58), I stepped down as a moderator on this site. At the time, the environment in the network and especially in moderator spaces was extremely toxic; I stepped down because I no longer felt safe in the role of moderator.

In the year and a half plus since then, there have been many steps - both by the community and the company that runs the site - to improve the situation. There have been many technical changes to the sites to improve things, many of the people from the company who were involved in the original mess have left, and I've spent many hours talking to people from the company (including lots of new faces since then) about how things can improve.
Given all that, I decided that I was once again comfortable taking on the mantle of moderator to help serve the needs of the community.

I requested reinstatement, and my request was approved by the CMs (and the other mods here agreed). So... here I am! Freshly re-diamonded, and ready to serve :)

-Mith

Comment: <3 Welcome back as a mod!!!! So very excited <3

Comment: Yay!!! Congratulations :D

Comment: ... what are the three downvotes on this supposed to mean?

Comment: Good news! Congratulations!

Comment: @bobble Four now?